# Splunk: Extracting values for table

Tags: search, splunk, splunk-query

I have events in my logs that look like

```
{
     linesPerSec:    1694.67    
     message:    Status:    
     rowCount:   35600000   
     severity:   info
}
```

when i make a search like:

```
index="apps"  app="my-api" message="*Status:*" | table  _time,  linesPerSec, rowCount
```

This is what my table ends up looking like
[image: This is what my table ends up looking like]

How do I get the number value away from the key for both linesPerSec and rowCount? I want to see all instances. I tried using values(linesPerSec) but that seemed to aggregate only unique.

Thanks,

Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer with explanation can be found here: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/756524/extracting-values-for-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Is that your complete query?  You mention using `values()`, but there's no `stats` command in your search.  BTW, `values()` displays unique values; use `list()` to see all of them.

You may be able to use `extract` to get the numbers, but I think `rex` will work better.  Try this search:

```
index="apps"  app="my-api" message="*Status:*" 
| rex "linesPerSec:\s+(?<linesPerSec>\d+\.\d+)" 
| rex "rowCount:\s+(?<rowCount>\d+)" 
| table  _time,  linesPerSec, rowCount
```